# Can't recognize hard disk via SATA

Tags: ssd, sata

I have Z170A Motherboard, and I cannot recognize my SSD when it's connected to the SATA port. I know the problem is not related to the drive, I tried to use a USB adapter, and then the driver got recognized.
Someone knows what can be done to make it work?

Comment: What do you get typing `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu as a live CD from my USB. This is what I get: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26030472/

Comment: Yep, seems your hardware does not recognise your SSD. Shouldn't be a Linux issue. Check the cables and also check within the BIOS.